# Where to place a global variable in Rails inside Nav

Tags: ruby-on-rails, global-variables

In my navbar, I have a variable perhaps `@categories = Category.all`. There is a drop down in the nav that lists the categories.

I'm wondering where I put this because it is a variable for the layout and not for a page. I thought about putting it in a controller, but that doesn't work.

Does this go the application helper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you need to display it in `navbar` within layout which I am assuming you need throughout the application, then all you have to do is:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_categories  ## Set a before_action

  ## ...

  def set_categories
    @categories = Category.all
  end
end
```

This way, since you define a `before_action` at `ApplicationController` level, `set_categories` method will be executed for each and every action throughout your application.